# How to get specific cookie from Node-Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, node-fetch

Is it possible to get a specific cookie from set-cookie in node fetch.js

```
var ResonseCookies = (SentRequest.headers.raw()['set-cookie']);
```

and it has returned me as i wanted

```
[
  'language=en; expires=Tue, 23-Feb-2021 00:55:18 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; secure; HttpOnly',
  'session.ID=22B9DB6FA61744AC857D417118C7650F; expires=Tue, 23-Feb-2021 00:55:19 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; secure; HttpOnly',
  'session.present=1; expires=Tue, 23-Feb-2021 00:55:19 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; secure'
]
```

is there anyway of just extracting the string
`22B9DB6FA61744AC857D417118C7650F` From the response.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since cookies are saved all together in a string, you can use methods like split(), find() and startsWith() to get exactly to the cookie key, for example:

```
const sessionID= document.cookie
.split('; ')
.find(row => row.startsWith('session.ID'))
.split('=')[1];
```

At the end you will convert the whole string in an array of 2 elements, the key and the value itself, therefore, position [1] in the array.

Another easier way, is to use the npm package [doc-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/doc-cookies). It presents simple methods to set, get and remove cookies, using the syntax:

```
docCookies.getItem('session.ID')
```

For setting the cookies in the first place:

```
docCookies.setItem('session.ID', 'yourCookieValue')
```